# Program not reading first String input

Tags: java, string, input

searched about 30 mins in the web and couldn't find this error anywhere. So, basically I have a method to find an email of someone in a matrix, in order to be able to change it. The problem is, when I enter case 1, my program only reads the input of "New email: " the second time I write it.

```
public static boolean atualizarInfoParticipante(String email,int nEl,String [][]equipas){

    int pos=Utilitários.pesquisarElemento1(email,nEl,equipas);
    String email2;
    if(pos!=-1){
        int op;

        do{
            Formatter out=new Formatter(System.out);
            Utilitários.mostrarParticipante(out,equipas[pos]);
            //op=Utilitários.menuParticipante(email);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("UPDATE USER INFO ",email);
            System.out.printf("\n");
            System.out.println("email - 1");
            System.out.println("Name - 2");
            System.out.println("Birth Date - 3");
            System.out.println("End - 0");
            op=ler.nextInt();
            ler.nextLine();

            switch(op){
                case 1: 
                        System.out.print("New email:");
                        email2=ler.nextLine();
                        if(Utilitários.pesquisarElemento1(email2,nEl,equipas)==-1){

                            equipas[pos][0]=ler.nextLine();
                        }
                        else{System.out.println("Email já existente. Alteração inválida.");}
                        break;}
```

This is only a part of the case, the only one with an error.

**output:**

```
   ac@abc.pt;   Ana Costa;  22/11/1999;    The Best;

UPDATE USER INFO
email - 1
Name - 2
Birth Date - 3
End - 0
1
New email:sss@abc.pt

        ;   Ana Costa;  22/11/1999;    The Best;
```

I've already tried to clear the buffer on innumerous spots, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you reading the email two times.

```
System.out.print("New email:");
email2=ler.nextLine();
```

You're reading email here and reading again here:

```
if(Utilitários.pesquisarElemento1(email2,nEl,equipas)==-1){

    equipas[pos][0]=ler.nextLine();
}
```

What I understood was, if the email doesn't exists you're reading it two times.
Please, put the name of the Class you're using to read too.

Comment: That's right, what a mistake by me. You solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: I'm not brazilian, I am Portuguese :)